# How can I configure the image created by the bootBuildImage command?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-native

Using [Spring Native](https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) and Gradle, with `bootBuildImage` Gradle command:

```
...
bootBuildImage {
    builder = 'paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny'
    environment = ['BP_NATIVE_IMAGE': 'true']
    imageName = "demo-native"
}
...
```

I can create a Docker image.

How can I configure the image, for example adding an `HEALTHCHECK` or modifying the `ENTRYPOINT` with a custom configuration the same way I can do within a Dockerfile???